# jinja2 expression to reference inventory collection to pass as parameter to shell script

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I have a hosts file myEnv with:

```
[myEnv:children]
app0
app1
app2
```

And a group file myEnv with:

```
env: "myEnv"
```

In the following playbook task I'm attempting to pass environment (value of env key) and list of apps in that environment (myEnv:children) to a shell script as parameters. Only the environment ('myEnv') is getting passed to the script. I'm unable to figure out correct jinja2 syntax to pass the list of apps associated with this key which is in my hosts file.

```
- name: Run createFacts.sh in bin directory
  command: ./createFacts.sh {{ env }} {{ hostvars[env] }}
  register: createPuppetFacts
  args:
    chdir: "{{binHome}}"
```

What jinja2 syntax do I require for this? I've scoured ansible docs and stack overflow and just not finding right format...other than errors in syntax the best I can do is get an empty string back!

Much appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Pass environment (value of env key) and list of apps in that environment (myEnv:children) to a shell script as parameters."*

A: Given the inventory

```
$ cat hosts
test_01
test_02
test_03

[app0]
test_01
test_02
test_03

[app1]
test_01
test_02

[app2]
test_02
test_03

[myEnv:children]
app0
app1
app2
```

and the group_vars

```
$ cat group_vars/myEnv 
env: "myEnv"
```

The playbook

```
$ cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - command: "/home/admin/createFacts.sh {{ env }}"
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
    - command: "/home/admin/createFacts.sh {{ groups[env] }}"
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

with the script

```
$ cat /home/admin/createFacts.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo $@
exit 0
```

gives

```
ok: [test_01] => {
    "result.stdout": "myEnv"
}

ok: [test_01] => {
    "result.stdout": "[utest_01, utest_02, utest_03]"
}
```

---

Notes

- `myEnv, app0, app1, app2` are groups. See [Inheriting variable values: group variables for groups of groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups)
- The value of `env` is `myEnv`. This is the name of a group. It's posible to list the members of the group `groups[env]`. But `hostvars[env]` must fail, because *hostvars* expects the name of a host as a parameter.
- Ansible does not provide the runtime with the information that the group `myEnv` is parent of the groups `app0, app1, app2`.
- There is a [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) *group_names*: "List of groups the current host is part of"

The task below

```
- debug:
    var: group_names
```

gives

```
ok: [test_01] => {
    "group_names": [
        "app0", 
        "app1", 
        "myEnv"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your prompt response. Your answer gave me more clarity in fixing my problem. With your help i was able to pass thru to my shell script the env, datacenter and applications on host. I had to scrub the 'u', ',' and brackets on prefix/suffix but it works.

I've decided rather than leverage a bash script (as some hosts can be windows) I'll probably end up using jinja2 templates against the inventory to push out these files.

Thanks again for your help Vlad!